# Installing RAGE with Discs

Tags: steam, rage

I am installing RAGE on my PC, after installing it fully I go to play and Steam wants me to download 17.9GB, would that be updates or what? I cant play until I download that and my internet is capped and I cant download is there away around this??

Comment: [these](http://www.overclock.net/t/1225133/how-can-i-play-my-steam-games-without-updating-them) [links](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3160-AGCB-2555) [may](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2573600) [help](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2606-RSDG-1296)